# User-implemented memory management

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I am given a C project assignment in which I am asked to implement a simple memory management library. The way it works is that it has init function which takes a pointer(void*) to a chunk of memory allocated by another c program along with the size of the chunk and has two other functions to allocate a block of requested size from the said chunk and deallocate a block when passed back the pointer pointing to it.

Problem is that I am asked to keep my management structures inside the chunk itself and I have zero idea on how to do that. I thought about dividing the chunk into frames but how can I keep track of which frames are allocated without using anything from outside the chunk?

Edit: Init function is used like this. There is this program which will call the library I am going to write. It will allocate a chunk of memory using either malloc or calloc. Then it will call the init function from the library and pass the pointer to that memory chunk along with the size of the chunk to it.

What my library will do with that chunk is to allocate blocks from it on demand. So my library's allocate function actually is a call to request a block of memory(size is passed as an argument) from the chunk. And it will return a (void *) pointer pointing to the allocated memory block.

Edit2: To make the situation more clear, my library has to be able to allocate and deallocate which means holes will appear in the chunk it is managing and it will employ either first-fit, best-fit or worst-fit.

Edit3: Is there a way to convert memory addresses into long int?

Comment: This is pretty much how the common `malloc` implementation is working. Try reading about it.

Comment: Be careful with your wording.  You say "a chunk of memory allocated by another C program" — that's unusual right there.  It would have to be shared memory if another program allocates the chunk of memory (or it would be memory allocated prior to a `fork()` and inherited by the child before an `exec*()` operation).  Otherwise, you can't directly access memory allocated by another process.  I'm not sure whether you mean "other C functions" or something else.  But the basic process for memory managers is normally to allocate a big chunk and dole out smaller pieces on demand.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I did. It didn't help.

Comment: Are you at least allowed a pointer or two outside the chunks to know where the list(s) of memory start?  I would assume so, but you should double check.

Comment: Also, a header (or footer) per allocated memory block that sits outside of the returned pointer to the user is a very common way of doing this.  Someone wants 32 bytes, you allocate `sizeof(YourHeader)+32` bytes, setup your linked lists to block or whatever, then return a pointer to the area the user is allowed to use.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan I am allowed a static array and some global variables but that is it. What I have in mind is to simply use to first n bytes of the chunk for a long int array then divide the rest of the chunk into frames of equal size. Long int array will have length equal to the number of frames whenever I pass a block(which may consist of multiple frames) I will write the pointer I passed into the array. So lets say I allocated 3rd, 4th, 5th frames and passed a pointer pointing to the start of the 3rd frame. Array[3] = Array[4] = Array[5] = pointer I passed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a rough idea of what you would need to do:

The memory segment should be structured as a linked list of blocks.  Each block starts with a copy of your management structure followed by the memory that you allocate.

On initialization, point the head of the linked list to the start of the given memory segment.  Set the size to the size of the segment minus the size of the management structure, and set the next pointer to NULL.

When the first allocation request is made, set the size of the head block to the requested size, then set the next pointer to the memory immediately after that.  Set the size of the new block to the old head size minus the requested size and the size of the management struct.

For a deallocation, you would need to find the block prior to the one you're about to release.  Change the size of the prior block to the size of the freed block plus the struct size, then change the next pointer to the freed block's next pointer.

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: How would you even deallocate memory blocks in such a structure or keep track of just which parts are currently allocated? Is it possible to use best-fit/worst-fit methods with such a structure?

Comment: @BerkErzin You could either have a flag in the struct saying whether the memory is available or in use, or you could maintain one list for available memory and one list for used memory.  In either case, you'd need some way to consolidate free blocks to reduce fragmentation.

Comment: If you want best fit (not great for fragmentation over time BTW), instead of finding the first free block that could possibly fit your memory, you search until you find an exact fit or until you hit the end of the free list and have the closest sized block that fulfills your needs.

Comment: worst fit is same as best-fit accept that you always grab the biggest chunk available I would guess.