# Memory Management with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I am developing a C library which has three functions. Init function takes a (void*) pointer to a memory chunk. I need to develop functions to allocate and deallocate memory blocks from that said chunk. What this means is that I have to keep track of which parts of the memory chunk I have allocated and which parts are free. Problem is, the structure I will implement to track the memory also has to be part of said memory chunk. I am not allowed to allocate new memory for my management structure.

And I have no idea how to do that.

Currently, I am planning to designate first few hundred bytes as header space and divide the rest into frames of equal size. I will use header space to create an array which will keep track of which frames are allocated. To do that, I need a way to convert memory address into long int so I can save them into the array and my search so far yielded nothing.

Is there any way to accomplish that? 
Failing that is there any other way to implement a management structure in this situation.

Comment: You should use integer offsets for everything within the memory chunk, not try to convert the pointers to integers.

Comment: "need a way to convert memory address into long int". You only need frame numbers if equal sized frames or offsets if not. In fact, for equal sized frames you can even save alot of space with a bit map for the free list.

Comment: That's right, just treat it as an array of frames.

Comment: Another common alternative is to put a small fixed sized header in front of each managed block and use that to chain up blocks.

Comment: All that said, this isn't really an appropriate question for SO. We're not a design discussion forum, you need to ask questions about specific code that you've written. So take the above advice and try to code something. If you can't get it to work, post what you wrote and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: [awkwardly written, but good basic malloc/realloc introduction](https://github.com/zyfjeff/C-HOW-TO/blob/master/c-malloc/Malloc_tutorial.pdf) Note, current implementations actually use `mmap` instead of `brk/sbrk` for managing the memory, but for a basic understanding how to approach the problems this isn't bad. If you are careful, you can extend to support 64-bit as well.

Comment: @Barmar: Stack Overflow is **not** a site “to ask questions about specific code that you've written.” That is a **subset** of what questions can be asked. The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says that, generally, questions about specific programming problems, software algorithms, software tools commonly used by programmers, and practical, answerable problems unique to software development are appropriate. Certainly questions about algorithm design are within those general areas, although it is better if they are somewhat more specific than this one.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My description may be a bit terse, but the point is that he needs to show something more specific that we can help correct, rather than asking for a general design.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291857/user-implemented-memory-management

Comment: @Barmar: The question does not ask for a general design. It asks “To do that, I need a way to convert memory address into long int so I can save them into the array and my search so far yielded nothing. Is there any way to accomplish that?” In this case, you can determine the question being asked by looking for the sentence with the question mark.The preceding part of the question sets context; it does not ask the question. (And, in fact, that preceding part of the question sketches a potential design; it does not request one.)

Answer (score 1):

> To do that, I need a way to convert memory address into long int so I can save them into the array and my search so far yielded nothing.
>
> Is there any way to accomplish that?

Generally, you do not need to convert memory addresses to an integer type merely to keep track of them. Options include:

- Work with pointers within the memory chunk you are given, using `char *` to perform arithmetic.
- Subtract the base address of the memory (again with `char *`) from pointers within it to get offsets of type `ptrdiff_t` (defined in `<stddef.h>`) and use those.
- Convert the addresses to the integer type `uintptr_t` (defined in `<stdint.h>`). Unlike the other options, this has implementation-dependent behavior. In common C implementations, the result of conversion will be a simple memory address that you can perform arithmetic on as expected. But, in some C implementations, the result will be more complicated, so the code will not be fully portable.